# Creating an XML file, via SimpleXML & simple_html_dom

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hope the title was OK.

My problem is that I want to generate an XML file, which contains all the ISO 4217 currencies, including their name, code and countries they are used in.

To do this I'm using simple_html_dom to grab the HTML, and select specific data from the page. Then using SimpleXML to construct the XML. I would like the output like so:

```
<currency>
    <code>USD</code>
    <name>United States Dollars</name>
    <location>United States of America</location>
</currency>
```

At the moment I can populate the code for all the codes, but cannot get the names or locations as well as the codes wrapped in currency

Here is the current code I have, the second for loop returns the names of the currency, but I can't figure out how to place this below the code tag within currency:

```
<?php


//Source: simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net
require('simple_html_dom.php');

//177 currencies
//set URL to parse
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217";
$html = file_get_html($url);
//find all <td> elements that are nested within <table class="wikitable"><tr> and put them into an array
$content = $html->find('table.wikitable tr td');


$newsXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<currencies></currencies>");
$newsXML->addAttribute('type', 'ISO_4217');
Header('Content-type: text/xml');

//loop to add each currency code in <currency><code>HERE</code></currency>
//this loop gets all the codes of the currencies
for($i = 0; $i <= 885; $i += 5){
    $currency = $newsXML->addChild('currency');
    $code = $currency->addChild('code',strip_tags($content[$i]));
}
//this loop gets all the names of the currencies
for($n = 3; $n <= 531; $n += 5){
    $name = $currency->addChild('name',strip_tags($content[$n]));   
}

//echo the XML
echo $newsXML->asXML();



?>
```

I have only started learning PHP a month or so back, so would appreciate any advice, or a point in the correct direction.

(Hope the formatting/title naming convention is OK).

Comment: Care to learn `XSLT`? Seems a perfect candidate for it... If you want to stick with your current method: don't query for the `td`'s, query for the `tr`'s, and inside a `foreach` loop through those `tr`'s, get the content of the 1st, 4th & 5th `td` child of that `tr` node.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Due to my high workload learning XSLT wouldn't be ideal. I'll try fetching the tr's instead, is my current method not possible then?
Thank you for the link Gordon I will take a look and use in the future.

Comment: Daniel: you're current method is possible, but doesn't work that good: (1) you are limiting yourself to a magic number, which may change (hence a `foreach` over `tr`'s), and (2) it's hard / cumbersome to get a reference to the right currency node if you loop the different properties separately, you'll have to store the node somewhere. If you loop `tr`'s, your `$currency` node is right there in scope.

Comment: I did as you said, grabbed tr's instead
    $code = strip_tags($tr->find('td', 0));
    $name = strip_tags($tr->find('td', 3));
    $location = strip_tags($tr->find('td',4));

The problem is there is a <tr> which contains <th> for the headings of the table, I've given up now and just resorted to echoing the XML tags, instead of creating them via SimpleXML, yes it's not correct, but the idea behind the file was to generate an XML file that would be uses elsewhere and shouldn't have had this much time put into it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the answer to this issue, and just ended up `echo`'ing the XML rather than constructing it via SimpleHTMLDom.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `$currency` in the second loop is static, resulting in something like

```
<currency>
  <code>foo</code>
</currency>
<currency>
  <code>bar</code>
</currency>
<currency>
  <code>baz</code>
  <name>nfoo</name>
  <name>nbar</name>
  <name>nbaz</name>
</currency>
```

You need to add both name and code to the same `$currency` object.